# java result really different from the expected one

Tags: java, calculus

I'm trying to output a really simple value, but what I obtain is really weird:

```
Log.d("try", "distanceWithMaxSpeed > " + ((90 * (1000 / 3600)) * ((3000 - 2000)/1000)) );
```

I get 0 instead of 25! Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer Division

`1000/3600 = 0`

You should change them to floats (`90f`) or doubles (`90.0`)

Answer (score 3):

You're doing integer division. If the numerator is less than the divisor, then at least one of the operands should be a `double`:

```
Log.d("try", "distanceWithMaxSpeed > " + ((90 * (1000.0 / 3600)) * ((3000 - 2000)/1000)) );
                                                     ^^
```

Comment: I simplified the example to post it, but I had two functions that return a double in the formula. But I used to obtain a zero though! By tailing every operand with the .0, everything works correctly :-)